# Writing a query that finds other users who have the same band in their favorite bands list and then listing the other users favorite bands

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble trying to write a query that is able to find other users who have the same band in their list of favorite bands as user1 and then listing the other users' other favorite bands.

So if user1 is John Smith, I'm trying to find other users who also like the same bands he likes and then list the other bands the other users like.

This is the query that I have written.

```
SELECT DISTINCT U.user_name, B.bname FROM bands B
JOIN favorites F ON B.bid = F.bid
JOIN users U ON F.uid = U.uid
WHERE B.bname IN (
    SELECT B.bname
    FROM favorites F
    JOIN bands B ON F.fav_band = B.bname
    WHERE F.uid = 1);
```

The results I want would be the other bands that Jane Doe likes besides Seputura (because her and John Smith share that in common. But the results I'm getting is:

[image]

I'm not too sure what to fix in my query to get the results desired. Would appreciate any help, thanks.

And these are the tables with data:

```
CREATE TABLE Bands (
    bid INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    bname CHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Bands (bname) VALUES ('Seputura'), ('Death'), ('Muddy Waters'), ('Led Zeppelin'), ('The Guess Who');
INSERT INTO Bands (bname) VALUES ('The Hu'), ('Huun-Huur-Tu'), ('Paul Pena'), ('Battuvshin'), ('Sade');
INSERT INTO Bands (bname) VALUES ('Mozart'), ('Tchaikovsky'), ('Twisted Sister'), ('Testament'), ('Tengger Cavalry');

CREATE TABLE users (
    uid INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_name CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    country CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (uid)
);

INSERT INTO users (uid, user_name, country) VALUES (DEFAULT, 'John Smith', 'United States');
INSERT INTO users (uid, user_name, country) VALUES (DEFAULT, 'Jane Doe', 'England');
INSERT INTO users (uid, user_name, country) VALUES (DEFAULT, 'Michael Hill', 'Russia');
INSERT INTO users (uid, user_name, country) VALUES (DEFAULT, 'Michelle Green', 'Brazil');

CREATE TABLE favorites (
    uid INT NOT NULL,
    bid INT NOT NULL,
    fav_band CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (uid, bid),
    FOREIGN KEY (uid) REFERENCES users(uid),
    FOREIGN KEY (bid) REFERENCES bands(bid)
);

INSERT INTO favorites (uid, bid, fav_band) VALUES (1, 1, 'Seputura');
INSERT INTO favorites (uid, bid, fav_band) VALUES (1, 4, 'Led Zeppelin');
INSERT INTO favorites (uid, bid, fav_band) VALUES (1, 9, 'Battuvshin');

INSERT INTO favorites (uid, bid, fav_band) VALUES (2, 1, 'Seputura');
INSERT INTO favorites (uid, bid, fav_band) VALUES (2, 5, 'The Guess Who');
INSERT INTO favorites (uid, bid, fav_band) VALUES (2, 10, 'Sade');
INSERT INTO favorites (uid, bid, fav_band) VALUES (2, 11, 'Mozart');

INSERT INTO favorites (uid, bid, fav_band) VALUES (3, 5, 'The Guess Who');
INSERT INTO favorites (uid, bid, fav_band) VALUES (3, 8, 'Paul Pena');

INSERT INTO favorites (uid, bid, fav_band) VALUES (4, 5, 'The Guess Who');
INSERT INTO favorites (uid, bid, fav_band) VALUES (4, 12, 'Tchaikovsky');
INSERT INTO favorites (uid, bid, fav_band) VALUES (4, 15, 'Tengger Cavalry');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT ub.user_name, b.bname 
FROM favorites fa 
JOIN favorites fb1 ON fa.bid = fb1.bid AND fa.uid <> fb1.uid
JOIN users ub ON fb1.uid = ub.uid
JOIN favorites fb2 ON ub.uid = fb2.uid
JOIN bands b ON fb2.bid = b.bid
WHERE fa.uid = 1
```

or using subquery

```
SELECT U.user_name, B.bname 
FROM bands B
JOIN favorites F ON B.bid = F.bid
JOIN users U ON F.uid = U.uid
WHERE U.uid IN (
    SELECT M.uid
    FROM favorites F
    JOIN favorites M ON F.bid = M.bid AND F.uid <> M.uid
    WHERE F.uid = 1
)
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9c9acf389bbb56209d0d23036acad275)

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully the comments in the SQL make it clear what the intent of each favorites join is.

```sql
/* FIND USERS AND THEIR BAND FAVOURITES WHICH I DO NOT ALREADY HAVE */
SELECT
    `u`.`user_name`,
    `b`.`bname`,
    /* if using MySQL >= 8.0 you can use COUNT(*) as a window function to
       get the count of users with this band as a favorite */
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY `b`.`bname`) AS `num_users`

/* John Smith's favorite bands */
FROM `favorites` `fav1`

/* other people's favourites */
INNER JOIN `favorites` `fav2`
    ON `fav1`.`bid` = `fav2`.`bid`
    AND `fav1`.`uid` <> `fav2`.`uid`

/* other people's favorite bands not in my favorites */
INNER JOIN `favorites` `fav3`
    ON `fav2`.`uid` = `fav3`.`uid`
    AND `fav1`.`bid` <> `fav3`.`bid`

INNER JOIN `bands` `b`
    ON `fav3`.`bid` = `b`.`bid`

INNER JOIN `users` `u`
    ON `fav3`.`uid` = `u`.`uid`

WHERE `fav1`.`uid` = 1 # John Smith

ORDER BY
    `num_users` DESC,
    `b`.`bname` ASC,
    `u`.`user_name` ASC
```

I suggest you remove `fav_band` from your junction table as it serves no useful purpose.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=07149a5cd65b6884c5188bba4bf16fe5)